# Mqtt publish/subscribe using c#

Tags: c#, mqtt, windows, mosquitto, paho

I've already worked with mqtt in Java. Now I need to create a C# application to subcribe and publish mqtt messages.

**using  MqttDotNet library**

```
IMqtt _client = MqttClientFactory.CreateClient(connectionString, clientId);
```

What is the `connectionString`?

**using  M2Mqtt library**

The connection succeeded, but I did not receive any published messages.

This is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new MqttClient(IPAddress.Parse("myTestIP"));

        // register to message received
        client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;

        var clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        client.Connect(clientId);

        // subscribe to the topic "/home/temperature" with QoS 2
        client.Subscribe(
            new string[] {"testTopic"},
            new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
    }

    static void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(
        object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
    {
        // handle message received
        Console.WriteLine("message=" + e.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

This my message publishing code:

```
mosquitto_pub -d -h testIp  -t "testTopic" -m "haai"
```

Comment: You shouldn't use MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE. 
Instead try to use  MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_LEAST_ONCE. 
Maybe the QoS 2 is not supported (for example, AWS IoT does not support it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the MqttDotNet is currently mantained.
I could suggest to use my M2Mqtt client and found documentation on official web site here :
https://m2mqtt.wordpress.com/

The M2Mqtt client is available on Nuget as package too here :
https://www.nuget.org/packages/M2Mqtt/

Paolo.

Comment: but using m2mqtt,  did not receive any published messages

Comment: can be more precise please ?

Comment: messages published by c# client (using m2mqtt library) is successfully getting in c# subscriber( using m2mqtt library). where as messages published from linux terminal is not got.  that is the actual issue.

Comment: Too few information ... on what's the client on Linux, what's the broker, what's the topic ...

Comment: this is the publish command from ubuntu terminal     mosquitto_pub -d -h testIp  -t "testTopic" -m "haai"

Comment: brocker is a cloud ip address

Comment: what's the broker ? HiveMQ, Mosquitto, GnatMQ ... ?

Comment: can you execute two distinct tests ? First try to use parameter "-q 2" for the mosquitto_pub to publish with QoS 2 (you are subscribed as QoS 2). Other test, try to use /testTopic instead simple testTopic.

Comment: However it's strange .... you can publish with a QoS but subscribe with a different QoS. The QoS is established between client and broker not between client and client. It seems to be a mosquitto bug on broker side ...

Comment: @ppatierno is your m2mqtt still being maintained? Last real commit was a while back. Can you suggest an alternative c# mqtt lib?

Answer (score 0):

The connection string is (according to the sample code documentation on Steven Lovegroves website http://www.stevenlovegrove.com/?id=37):

Connection Strings

- TCP connection, eg. tcp://brokerhost.com:1883
- Bluetooth connection, eg. bt://00:10:dc:af:66:48